# How to get columns of belongs_to table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

college.rb

```
has_many :tenant_colleges
```

tenant_college.rb

```
belongs_to :college
```

I want to get attribute name of college along with all tenant_college attributes

I do

```
TenantCollege.select("tenant_colleges.*, colleges.name").joins(:college)
```

But it doesn't give college name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), like  this

```
   tenant_colleges = TenantCollege.includes(:colleges)
    tenant_colleges.each do |tc|
      puts tc.college.name
    end
```

**EDIT**
Like @lcguida suggested its better to go with two separate queries. If you want to get that in a single query use the `.select` method as we normally do

```
TenantCollege.joins(:colleges).select("tenant_colleges.*, colleges.name")
```

**OR**

```
TenantCollege.joins("LEFT JOIN colleges ON tenant_colleges.id = colleges.tenant_id")
  .select('tenant_colleges.*', 'colleges.name')
```

Answer (score 1):

> - I want to get attribute name of college along with all tenant_college
>     attributes

As I gone through [belongs-to-association-reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) and [has-many-association-reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference), There is no build in method available. But its easy with little hack.

```
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
    def get_college_with_tenant_colleges
      _ary = {}
      _ary[:user] = self
      _ary[:tenant_colleges] =  self.tenant_colleges
      _ary
    end
  end
```

But to make sure that the r`eturn type` of this method is **Hash** not `ActiveRecord`. So In order to get the all method of `ActiveRecord` you need to `iterate`.
Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you wouldn't use raw SQL for something like this, but the following code ought to work:

`TenantCollege.joins(:college).pluck("tenant_colleges.*", "colleges.name")`

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by setting specific name for sql column:

```
results = TenantCollege.select("tenant_colleges.*, colleges.name AS college_name").joins(:college)
results[0].college_name
```